# Time is wrong when get datetime in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a problem when I get datetime in my yii2 project. When I get datetime, the date is true but the time is wrong. I execute my code and the result is :

> 2016-05-02 12:30:28

whereas the time in my laptop is : 19:30. What's the problem? I use time in Indonesia. This is my code:

```
$time = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$model->tanggal_sampai = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the time in the `UTC` time zone with `new \DateTimeZone('UTC')`.  Either ask for it in your own time zone, which I think is `WIB`:

```
$time = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('WIB'));
```

or without a time zone:

```
$time = new \DateTime('now');
```

Comment: @ariefsibuea : If this answer helped you. Please mark this answer as correct. As it will help other user to find it easily. And, if you don't know how to mark answer as correct answer. Please go through this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

First, Find out the `timezone` for **Indonesia** from [List Of Supported TimeZones - php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Then, make it common for all places using **config.php** file. Add `'timeZone'=>'Your TimeZone',` after `components` section.

**Example** : **config.php**

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
  'id' => 'basic',
  'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
  'bootstrap' => ['log'],
  'components' => [ 
        .
        .
        .
    ],
    'timeZone'=>'Asia/Kolkata',
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.