# Swiftmailer Time Exception yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a yii2 project. I make sending email function on it, so I use yii2 swiftmailer. But I have a problem. Sometimes my connection is bad, so when the function is running my application will stop because the time for sending email is just 30 seconds. So, how can I handle the error exception? May be I can use try-catch, but I don't know how to use it for handle time exception.

Comment: How You Knew That "*..time for sending email is just 30 seconds*" ? In which file it is coded ?

Comment: And, Till Now You Have Not Responded To The Answer Of Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982547/time-is-wrong-when-get-datetime-in-yii2

Comment: I know it from the error