# Display data from database using popover-x

Tags: php, yii2

I have a yii2 project. I install popover-x from kartik on it. I use popover for display list of date, but I have a problem to do that. I use ArrayHelper to get data from database before. But it's wrong and I get error:

> Array to string conversion

Then, I change my code but it's still wrong and I get the same error. What's my problem? This is my code:

```
[
     'format' => 'raw',
     'label' => 'Action',
     'value' => function($model)
     {
          $data = \frontend\models\Paket::find()->select(['tanggal_sampai'])->where(['status' => 0])->all();
          $content = [];
          foreach ($data as $d)
          {
                $content[] = ['tanggal_sampai' => $d['tanggal_sampai']];
          }

          return PopoverX::widget([
                'header' => 'Pesa terkirim',
                'placement' => PopoverX::ALIGN_BOTTOM,
                'size' => 'md',
                'content' => $content,
                'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'Daftar Pesan', 'class'=>'btn btn-default'],
          ]);
     }
],
```

Comment: And, why are you not responding to our answers. Till now you have asked 10 Questions And Selected Only 1 Answer Out Of Them. And, even you are not responding to our comments. People here spend their times/efforts to help each and every individual. I reminded you in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053798/swiftmailer-time-exception-yii2 yesterday itself. But, no reply. I asked the same in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982547/time-is-wrong-when-get-datetime-in-yii2 But, same result.

Comment: I'm Observing you since last week. You ask question -> After that escape for 15 hours -> Come again ->Ask fresh question. If this is your daily routine/nature. Then, you are not going to get any help from us.